# Visual representation of $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1$

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I'm trying to create a proper explanation in the cartesian coordinate system as to why $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1$.

Although I could go with the derivative, I figured that it'd be a nice alternative if I could show that the two functions are symmetrical to $0.5$, but cannot for the life of me proceed from there

Any recommendations?

Comment: Did you think about using Pythagoras?

Answer (score 1):

One visual interpretation could be plotting the unit circle centered at origin in the Cartesian plane and then switching to polar coordinates.

Let $P(x,y)$ be a point on the circle. Then, $x^2+y^2=1$.

Switching to polar coordinates, $x=\cos\theta$ and $y=\sin\theta$ with $0\leq\theta\lt 2\pi$ which shows $\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1~\forall~\theta\in [0,2\pi)$.

Now, since $2\pi$ is a period for any circular trigonometric functions, this shows the above holds for all $\theta\in\Bbb R$ (if $\theta\in [0,2\pi)^c$, think of the angle mod $2\pi$ where you take the non-negative remainder as $\theta$; the angle $\theta$ is increasing counter-clockwise).